# Multiple checkbox can't access from JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I have dynamic multiple check boxes which is used to restore multiple files. It works perfectly when I have more than 1 check boxes. Here is my php code for check boxes:

```
<form name="RestoreFile">
    <input type="checkbox" title="'.$FldDoc['FldDocumentName'].'" name="restore_checkbox" value="'.$FldDoc['FldDocumentID'].'" id="restore_'.$NodeId.'_'.$FldDoc['FldDocumentID'].'"/>
    <input type="button" value="Restore" onclick="RestoreDocFile(\''.$NodeId.'\',this.form.restore_checkbox);" />
</form>
```

And the definition of function RestoreDocFile() is given below:

```
function getSelected(opt) 
{
    var selected = new Array();
    var index = 0;
    for (var intLoop = 0; intLoop < opt.length; intLoop++) {
       if (opt[intLoop].checked) 
       {
          index = selected.length;
          selected[index] = new Object;
          selected[index].value = opt[intLoop].value;
          selected[index].index = intLoop;
       }
    }
    return selected;
}

function RestoreDocFile(nodeid, opt)
{   
    var getSelectDocIds = getSelected(opt);
//alert(nodeid+','+getSelectDocIds);    
        var strSelectedDocIds = "";
        var i=0;
        for (var item in getSelectDocIds)
        {
           if(i!=0)
           {
                strSelectedDocIds+=":";
           }    
           strSelectedDocIds += getSelectDocIds[item].value ;
           i++;
        }
}
```

The problem is that if there has 1 checkbox at the time of form load it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
onclick="RestoreDocFile(\''.$NodeId.'\',this.form.restore_checkbox);"
```

with

```
onclick="RestoreDocFile(\''.$NodeId.'\',this.form.getElementsByName(\'restore_checkbox\'));"
```

This will ensure you get a NodeList regardless of how many checkboxes there are.

Comment: It gives an error like this:- this.form.getElementsByName is not a function

Comment: I have done it in this way.And it works fine.

    var getSelectDocIds = new Array();
        $.each($("input[name='restore_checkbox']:checked"), function(){
        getSelectDocIds.push($(this).val());
        });
         
        var strSelectedDocIds ='';   
        var i=0;
        for (var item in getSelectDocIds)
        {
            if(i!=0)
            {
                strSelectedDocIds+=":";
            }    
            strSelectedDocIds += getSelectDocIds[item];
            i++;
        }